# Recursion or list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

Working through *Learn You a Haskell For Great Good*, in the chapter on higher-order functions the author walks through an implementation of a few different library functions. When coming to the definition of `filter'` (a reimplementation of the standard library function `filter`), I thought that the obvious thing was this:

```
filter' f xs = [x | x <- xs, f x]
```

But the author gives the following longer, recursive definition:

```
filter' _ [] = []  
filter' p (x:xs)   
    | p x       = x : filter' p xs  
    | otherwise = filter' p xs
```

Both definitions do the same thing. Is there any reason for this? Is the recursive definition somehow more performant? Is it more idiomatic for Haskell? Something else?

Comment: `filter'` can also be written in terms of the higher-order function `foldr` as in `filter' p = foldr (\x ys -> if p x then x : ys else ys) []`, although that would be a better example of a use of a higher order function than how to build one "from scratch".

Comment: See [Haskell 2010 > Expressions > List Comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) if you are interested in how they desugar.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's probably because the list comprehension is just syntactic sugar, which in principle is translated to the recursive form.

If the authors point is to illustrate how the function is implemented, using a list comprehension shortcut doesn't really do that - it shows an alternative way to express the solution, but not really a functional implementation.

In short, it's showing how to implement from a fairly minimal set of basic building blocks.

This is a guess, though - I haven't read that tutorial myself.

Answer (score 8):

List comprehension is pretty much sugar for a map and a filter in one operation; Although it may use concatMap in the backend. Generally using something of higher abstraction to implement something of lower abstraction is cheating.

Comment: You can't implement list comprehensions in terms of just map and filter, you really need concatMap.

Comment: @augustss Why do you think I mentioned specifically that it uses concatMap? And what I was getting at is that filter is basically part of concatMap.

Comment: "may use" didn't sound like "must use". :)

Comment: @augustss Of course it doesn't have to use, you could reimplement the whole thing.

Comment: I think augustss's point here is that `concatMap` fully subsumes `map` and `filter`, as well as doing things that they can't, and that any reimplementation for creating list comprehensions will necessarily be equivalent to `concatMap`.

Comment: List comprehensions can be thought of as working within the list monad with assignment corresponding to bind and conditions indicating a guard. The bind implementation requires `concatMap`, as noted, and `map` and `filter` alone will not do. You cannot implement `concatMap` in terms of `map` and `filter` to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Sujay concatMap = concat . map... Yeah, implemented in terms of map, and then filter can be implemented with concat Map